# I want quilljs in nuxt.js (vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, quill, wysihtml5, nuxt.js

I know vue-quill-editor.

However, I am having difficulties.

First, I started with

```
vue vue-init nuxt / express myProject
```

and

```
npm install --save vue-quill-editor
```

~plugins/quill.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

if (process.BROWSER_BUILD) {
  require('quill/dist/quill.snow.css')
  require('quill/dist/quill.bubble.css')
  require('quill/dist/quill.core.css')
  Vue.use(require('vue-quill-editor/ssr'))
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: [
  { src: '~plugins/quill.js' }
]
```

Is this the right way?

How do I add modules here?
For example,

```
Import {ImageImport} from '../modules/ImageImport.js'
Import {ImageResize} from '../modules/ImageResize.js'
Quill.register ('modules / imageImport', ImageImport)
Quill.register ('modules / imageResize', ImageResize)
```

I could refer to the following,

but it does not seem to be an example of a nuxt.js environment. So I failed.

https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor/tree/master/examples

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look this package: [Vue Quill Editor](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor). This package has example for `NuxtJS` in [here](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor/tree/master/examples/nuxt-ssr-example). I've been successful with this.

Comment: could you also manage to run it with "nuxt generate"? Because the universal version runs fine, but generated version ends up with "document is not defined"?

Comment: There is this now: https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/ which works with this: https://github.com/vueup/vue-quill/issues/161#issuecomment-1050066966

Answer (score 1):

The best pratice is to use the `ssr: false` option in plugins to run the file only on the client-side.

`nuxt.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    { src: '~plugins/quill.js', ssr: false }
  ],
}
```

Check the Nuxt doc: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#client-side-only

Comment: But in this case rendered html will not be equal to html in browser and vue will bail the hydration to perform full client-side rerender

Answer (score 0):

quills is for vue2 and vue3. if you are using nuxtjs that use vue2 you have to use this [enter link description here](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor)

if you are using vuejs 3 you can use this [enter link description here](https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/)